# write a service to detect a particular file has been received over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service

I am developing an android application where I am able to successfully transfer a file with extension ".Xcard" over bluetooth.

Now what I want to do is, when the file is received I want it to automatically cut-paste from bluetooth folder to my application's folder.

How should I do this?
Any hint??
please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829373/how-to-determine-when-a-bluetooth-file-is-received 
I think we are looking for the same thing.