# How to determine when a bluetooth file is received?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-bluetooth

In my app, I need to edit an bluetooth-transferred file just after it is received.

**Exactly what Intent do I have to listen to with my BroadcastReceiver, in order to find out when a file has been received via Bluetooth?**

Also, please tell me if there are other solutions.

Comment: Do you have some code how you connect? Or do you can already read from bluetooth?

Comment: @silvia: I don't want to connect or receive, I just want to be informed when a file has been successfully received.

Comment: yes but you need a connection and a read function. Otherwise you won't get it. And my question was if you have this already or not.

Comment: Ok maybe I'm missing the point. At the point a user gets a file via android O.S, I want to invoke my service to do something. Now don't we have any Intents like Bluetooth_Received_File?! I know I can use Google Example to create a Server Socket and receive a file. then what?

Answer (score 2):

If the user gets a file via android OS, it's via the download manager.
in that case u should register DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                //your code here
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, filter);

}
```

Comment: Nice, how to understand if the downloaded file was received via bluetooth?