# Android Broadcast Receiver filter when a file was received via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

As like the title said, is there such filter?

i tried the following:

[How to determine when a bluetooth file is received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829373/how-to-determine-when-a-bluetooth-file-is-received)

does not work unfortunately.

In addition to my question, after receiving the file via bluetooth, how can i get the details of the file that was received?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `FileObserver` instead, listened for `CREATE` action from the Bluetooth Folder and get the file name then Listened for a `ACL_DISCONNECT` from a broadcast receiver.